# SmtpClient.Timeout on MonoTouch (iOS), does not seem to have any effect, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, smtp, timeout

I am building a "test" button to verify SMTP configuration in an app.

If the user types in an incorrect port number, switches SSL on/off to the incorrect state, or types in a valid domain name, but one that isn't hosting an SMTP server, the app hangs, waiting for a timeout.

Basically, it found a server, but is unable to connect to the specified port.

This timeout seems to be about 1 minute 15 seconds in this case.

I tried setting the timeout like this:

```
var client = new SmtpClient(hostname, port);
client.Timeout = 15000; // milliseconds
```

but the timeout is still around 1 minute 15 seconds.

Is there anything else I need to configure?

Note that while I can use "SendAsync" to avoid the hang, I still want to use a bit lower timeout in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This could be related to DNS resolution which is [done synchronously](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2012-February/007804.html). You can confirm this easily by using an IP address, instead of a host name, and see if the timeout gets closer to the expected 15 seconds.

If that's the case then a possible alternative, that I have **not** tested under iOS, *could* be to use [Mono.Dns](http://gonzalo.name/blog/archive/2011/Oct-09.html).

Comment: No, I doubt that. I did use the right hostname in my trials, which does in fact resolve to the correct server. However, I had toggled the SSL setting incorrectly to test that, which made the program attempt to connect to the server on the wrong port, then the delay of 1:15 comes into play. If I type in a completely nonexistant domain name, I get quick feedback about that, so this isn't that. The server does exist, it just doesn't respond on port 25.